# Preventing setting regression with configuration tied to a build

Tags: design, architecture, testing, data

I have inherited a distributed application with a lot of legacy configuration management.

Currently the application does not get it's settings updated with an application update. The flow looks something like this:

1. The application is updated. The only settings that are defined are one's with hard-coded defaults.
2. A separate workflow pushes a configuration to correct the application state from a separately maintained "gold" config.
3. A user may manually change settings on the application.
4. A user may request the workflow from 2 be re-run with some setting change.

Because the application is running at a scale for 3000+ instances, manually doing anything is very error-prone so we have another workflow that detects any setting that is drifted from it's "gold" value.

To lower the complexity, I have suggested we move the "gold" config into the repo and evaluate it at build time.

I've had a few holes poked in that but it feels like the right direction. Specifically other stakeholders are worried that we would introduce a setting regression on a hotfix.